Trouble with flipping the normals
I'm working on a piece of clothing in Blender 4.2.  I enabled the option to show "Face Orientation", and everything is looking right. The blue sides are facing outwards.

But in Unreal Engine 5, the textures are inside instead of outside.

There are no modifiers waiting to be enabled, and the object's origin point is inside.
I have many other objects in the same blender file and they don't have any problem with inside-out materials when imported into Unreal.
I made it by copying my character, discarding the unwanted faces, scaling the ones I wanted, and then using the mirror modifier and the cloth modifier.
I noticed that the dress' vertices were duplicated, so I merged them all by distance and thought that this would solve the problem, but any attempt to recalculate the normals in any way doesn't seem to help.
I also tried flipping them so that red shows outside, and doing this, the textures do appear on the outside as they should, but they seem to be showing what would normally be inside, because it's all shadowed.

Normally it should look like this: 

just a guess, have you applied the scale? If it's negative this can flip the normals when you export the mesh.

Wow, correct guess! Thank you! The X scale was negative in object mode. Is there a way to mark your comment as the solution?

Ha! Don't let the scale fool you! ;-) Comments cannot be accepted as solutions. But I've posted it as an answer so you can accept it now.

Check if you have applied the Scale to the object. A negative scale value can flip the normals when you export the mesh.
The scale is displayed in the viewport's side panel (N) and should be (1.0, 1.0, 1.0).
Here is an example and how to fix it (apply scale and recalculate/flip normals if needed).
